# How to tell what SSL/TLS protocols allowed from my client application?

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, client-server, weblogic

I have a client application communicating with external party application. The client application is up and running for long time.

Recently, I received a request from the third party asking about the allowed SSL/TLS protocols from the application server where my client application is running and calling their application.

**Questions**

How to tell what SSL/TLS protocols allowed from my client application ?

**What has been done so far**

**1 -** I checked SSL configration at the server's browser where my client application is running, See below screen shot. Is this what the third party team trying to know?

[image: SSL_Setting_On_Browse]

**2 -** The client application is running from weblogic 10.3.6. I cheked weblogic configuration in the following but I could not find any thing about the SSL/TLS protoclos used:

**2.1 -** Summary of Servers >Server_1 >Protocols

**2.2 -** Summary of Servers >Server_1 >Configuration >SSL

**------ Update ------**

I am using Java 7 for the client application. For that I checked the [Java™ Secure Socket Extension (JSSE)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#SupportClasses) documentation online. In the online documentation I found the following

> **Engine Class Implemented** : SSLContext
>
> **Algorithm or Protocol:** SSLv3 (a.k.a. SSL), TLSv1 (a.k.a. TLS), TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2

See documentation [Java Cryptography Architecture Oracle Providers Documentation for Java Platform Standard Edition 7, The SunJSSE Provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider) for more information.

So is this the allowed SSL/TLS protocols from my client application? Further if Java has its own allowed Protocols, then how is that related to protocols setting in the browser ( Point 1 above )?

Comment: It depends entirely on the Java version you are using. The supported TLS protocols for each Java release are documented in the JSSE Reference Guide.

Comment: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24422/ssl.htm#SECMG634 (there are similar settings for 11G)

The browser settings are a red herring - the third-party app will connect to weblogic, not your browser, and negotiate a secure protocol based on what WLS + the third party app can mutually support.

Java7's default settings are acceptable, although if you need PCI-DSS compliance, you should probably set TLS1.1 as the minimum.